# R: How to get factor levels found in data

Tags: r, r-factor

How can I list factor levels that exist in the data?

Let's initialize data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    v1 = c( 'b', 'c', 'a', NA ),
    v2 = c( 2, 1, 3, 1 )
)
df$v1 <- factor(
    df$v1,
    levels = c( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ),
    ordered = TRUE
)
```

Now, `levels()` gives all the levels, including those not found in the data:

```
> levels( df$v1 )
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

And `unique()` gives all the unique values, including `NA`:

```
> unique( df$v1 )
[1] b    c    a    <NA>
Levels: a < b < c < d
```

What I'm looking for, is something in the lines of:

```
> levels( df$v1, indata = TRUE )
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: see `?droplevels`

Comment: As in `levels(droplevels(df$v1))` to display the non-zero levels or `df$v1 <- droplevels(df$v1)` to remove them from the data frame.

Comment: @dcarlson, `levels( droplevels( df$v1 ) )` gives exactly the result I was looking for and is simple. Thank you! Please, make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `droplevels`

```
levels(droplevels(df$v1))
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Or just wrap `factor` again to reset the `levels`

```
levels( factor(df$v1) )
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: I would have thought that the latter would have reseted the order of level to alphabetical order, but apparently that is not the case (which is nice):

    df <- data.frame(
        v1 = c( 'b', 'c', 'a', NA )
    )
    df$v1 <- factor(
        df$v1,
        levels = c( 'b', 'a', 'd', 'c' ),
        ordered = TRUE
    )

    levels( factor( df$v1 ) ) # => "b" "a" "c"

Comment: @teppo You used `ordered` which prevented as the attribute was not removed

Comment: @teppo i.e. the `class` is not changed after calling the factor `> class(df$v1)#
[1] "ordered" "factor" 
> class(factor(df$v1))#
[1] "ordered" "factor" `

Comment: Yes. I thought that it would only look at the data but it actually uses the class info as well.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use `unique`, then subset to filter out the NAs?

```
Filter(unique(df$v1, \(x) !is.na(x))
```

we can also use base subsetting:

```
unique(df$v1[!is.na(df$v1)])
```

or we can use `purrr::discard`

```
library(purrr)

unique(df$v1) %>% discard(is.na)
```

Comment: I don't like `unique()` since it does not necessarely give the unique values in the order of the levels.